# @Message annotation doesn't work when I run atmosphere-chat-multiroom of atmosphere-samples

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, websocket, atmosphere

I've searched about this issue for a long while but no solution comes for me.

Here is some code (I've just added some `System.out.println` phrases).

web.xml

```
<display-name>Atmosphere Chat</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/chat/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ChatRoom.java

```
@ManagedService(path = "/chat/{room}")
public class ChatRoom {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    private final static String CHAT = "/chat/";

    @PathParam("room")
    private String room;

    @Inject
    private BroadcasterFactory factory;

    @Inject
    private AtmosphereResourceFactory resourceFactory;

    @Inject
    private MetaBroadcaster metaBroadcaster;

    private static Collection<String> getRooms(Collection<Broadcaster> broadcasters) {
        Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Broadcaster broadcaster : broadcasters) {
            if (!("/*".equals(broadcaster.getID()))) {
                // if no room is specified, use ''
                String[] p = broadcaster.getID().split("/");
                result.add(p.length > 2 ? p[2] : "");
            }
        };
        return result;
    }
    @Ready(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class})
    @DeliverTo(DeliverTo.DELIVER_TO.ALL)
    public ChatProtocol onReady(final AtmosphereResource resource) {
        System.out.println("Client " + resource.uuid() + " connected.");
        return new ChatProtocol(users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
    }

    @Disconnect
    public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            System.out.println("Client " + event.getResource().uuid() + " unexpectedly disconnected.");
        } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {
            System.out.println("Client " + event.getResource().uuid() + " closed the connection");
        }
    }

    @Message(decoders = {UserDecoder.class})
    public void onPrivateMessage(UserMessage user) {
        System.out.println("Client " + user.getUser() + " send a message.");
        String userUUID = users.get(user.getUser());
        if (userUUID != null) {
            // Retrieve the original AtmosphereResource
            AtmosphereResource r = resourceFactory.find(userUUID);

            if (r != null) {
                ChatProtocol m = new ChatProtocol(user.getUser(), " sent you a private message: " + user.getMessage().split(":")[1], users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
                if (!user.getUser().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
                    factory.lookup(CHAT + room).broadcast(m, r);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ChatProtocol m = new ChatProtocol(user.getUser(), " sent a message to all chatroom: " + user.getMessage().split(":")[1], users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
            metaBroadcaster.broadcastTo("/*", m);
        }
    }

    @Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {ProtocolDecoder.class})
    public ChatProtocol  onMessage(ChatProtocol message) throws IOException {
        if (message.getMessage().contains("disconnecting")) {
            users.remove(message.getAuthor());
            return new ChatProtocol(message.getAuthor(), " disconnected from room " + room, users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
        }

        if (!users.containsKey(message.getAuthor())) {
            users.put(message.getAuthor(), message.getUuid());
            return new ChatProtocol(message.getAuthor(), " entered room " + room, users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
        }

        message.setUsers(users.keySet());
        return new ChatProtocol(message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage(), users.keySet(), getRooms(factory.lookupAll()));
    }
}
```

When I run this sample in IntelliJ IDEA, the websocket can establish. And all of functions works fine except `@Message` annotation, I can choose a chatroom means `@Ready` annotation works cause console log prints like below.

> Client 6c981440-0ae6-43ed-be40-95dfad23d586 connected.

When I close my browser, console log is

> Client 6c981440-0ae6-43ed-be40-95dfad23d586 closed the connection

which means `@Disconnect` works.

But I type a name in `input` and click enter. Nothing happened.
[image: Choose Name]

Anyone can help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: The run environment is JDK1.7, tomcat7 and atmosphere-runtime version is 2.4.3. I've debug this yesterday, after I typed a name, `IllegalArgumentException` was catched in code below.

```
    public static Object invokeMethod(Method method, Object objectToInvoke, Object... parameters) {
    Object objectToEncode = null;
    boolean hasMatch = false;

    try {
        objectToEncode = method.invoke(objectToInvoke, method.getParameterTypes().length == 0?new Object[0]:parameters);
        hasMatch = true;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException var6) {
        logger.trace("", var6);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException var7) {
        logger.error("", var7);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException var8) {
        logger.trace("", var8);
    } catch (Throwable var9) {
        logger.error("", var9);
    }

    if(!hasMatch) {
        logger.trace("No Method\'s Arguments {} matching {}", method.getName(), objectToInvoke);
    }

    return objectToEncode;
}
```

which code is in **org\atmosphere\atmosphere-runtime\2.4.3\atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar!\org\atmosphere\config\managed\Invoker.class**

Answer (score 1):

I've met this issue, and maybe the `encoders` and `decoders` caused this problem, try to change your method parameter to `String`.